# Web.py How to access render function in this case

Tags: python, web.py

I am new to Python and Web.py, but I am tearing my hair out over this issue. I have a code layout where I have my `app.py` file in the root of my site. All the pages are in a sub director, named `pages`. Here is my app.py code

```
import web
import page.index

urls = (
    '/', 'page.index.index',
)

render = web.template.render('templates/', base = "layout") # Start the template 
app = web.application(urls, globals()) # Start the app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Now, it executes perfectly. Now, in the index.py file, this is my code:

```
class index:
    def GET(self):
        testing = 'Hello World'
        return render.index(testing)
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
<type 'exceptions.NameError'> at /
global name 'render' is not defined
Python  /Volumes/Local Disk 2/Work/Casting Board/com/index.py in GET, line 3
Web     GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

Basically, I am trying to access the function ( or it is method or class. Just coming from PHP so don't know the terminally) `render` from a moucle called page.index. How can I get around this?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to just use `import pages`. Which will look for a pages folder? See https://github.com/alexksikes/mailer/blob/master/application.py for an example of what it seems you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the index.py page, should you include `from web.template import render` ?

Comment: From my understanding, 'render = web.template.render('templates/', base = "layout")' loads the files as functions. I can do what you said, but it does not have the required functions to work, as it has not been setup. Any help?

Comment: Look at the error message `global name 'render' is not defined` it says that it is not finding the definition of `render`. BTW, in your comment, are you sure want to to overload the definition of `render` by doing an assignment?

Comment: I am trying to get the 'render' registered as a global. It all works if I put the index class in the app.py file, but as soon as I separate the two, it breaks. I need to know a way around this, so I can call render.index() from another file. It might be that I can't?

Comment: We don't say it as global. You can import an object (module, class, function) from one module to another so that it is can used in another module. Only thing to avoid is circular import a -> b -> a. If not, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming `web.template.render()` returns an object containing an `index()` method (I'm not familiar with `web.py`), you'll need to tell Python where to find this object.

In `index.py`:

```
import app
```

Then:

```
    return app.render.index(testing)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just include you index class (index.py) within your app.py file. Importing the web module then will bring in the definition of the function "render" at the beginning of your code.